# 32 bit audio to 24 bit

Tags: c++, audio

I'm trying to convert 32 bit audio data into 24 bit audio. However, when I try to play it all I get is noise. It seems I'm missing something very basic?

It should be little endian raw PCM.

```
template<typename T>
static std::vector<int8_t> audio_32_to_24(const T& audio_data)
{   
    auto size        = std::distance(std::begin(audio_data), std::end(audio_data));
    auto input8      = reinterpret_cast<const int8_t*>(&(*std::begin(audio_data)));
    auto output8     = std::vector<int8_t>();

    output8.reserve(size*3);
    for(int n = 0; n < size; ++n)
    {
        output8.push_back(input8[n*4+1]);
        output8.push_back(input8[n*4+2]);
        output8.push_back(input8[n*4+3]);
    }

    return output8;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, or simply inspecting the input and output to your function?#

Comment: you may want to specify (a) encoding (assuming raw PCM) (b) endianness (assuming big-endian); Also, may I suggest using a library (like **[`libsox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net)**); Did you try reversing the byte ordering for output? It seems wrong, but I can't tell from the info

Comment: Very unusual to have 32-bit integer PCM.  Surely it is a float?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Difficult to make much sense of the values since it's displayed as bytes instead of 24 bit.

Comment: @Hans: It is a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @sehe: I would prefer not using a library for such a simple thing. I've tried reversing.

Comment: @ronag: The conversion isn't difficult... (`a << 16 + b << 8 + c`).  You probably only need to do this once to establish what the problem is.

Comment: Also, C++ has rules on what can alias to what, and I think you might be violating them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule.  Specifically in this case, you're casting directly from audio_data's type to int8_t*.  I think you have to go through char* first.  Not sure if int8_t counts as a char* type or not for this rule, which is why I'm leaving a comment, not an answer :P

Comment: FWIW some (many?) audio libraries expect each 24-bit audio sample to be stored with 1 byte of padding while the audio is in memory, so that the audio samples will be 32-bit-aligned for better performance.  That is, it's only when the file is on disk that the 4th byte of each sample is omitted to save space.  If that's true, and you're handing 24-bit packed audio to one of those libraries to play, that would explain why it comes out as white noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is LE too, the output byte ordering seems inverted:

```
    output8.push_back(input8[n*4+3]);
    output8.push_back(input8[n*4+2]);
    output8.push_back(input8[n*4+1]);
```

**Edit** For sheer fun, I'd consider replacing it with this (since it looks like you might be using C++0x:

```
size_t i = 0;

std::copy_if(
    reinterpret_cast<const int8_t*>(&*std::begin(audio_data)),
    reinterpret_cast<const int8_t*>(&*std::end(audio_data)),
    std::back_inserter(output),
    [&i] (int) { return 0 == (i++ % 4); });
```

Also, consider replacing the

- `reserve` with `resize`
- the `push_back` or *output iterator* with a direct iterator into the target container

Comment: deleting because of confirmation by OP

Comment: Added a little off-topic play. It might turn out to be more efficient.